# Hypotesis test to multi categorical data

Tags: r, hypothesis-testing

I want to verify if the difference in a temperature between three groups: smokers, no smokers and ex smokers. What is the most appropriate test? 
(data is non-normal)

Comment: What about some good old ANOVA? ANOVA can be fairly robust for moderate violation of normality.

Comment: @QmmmmLiu: A possibility, of course (+), but OP _explicitly stated_ data non-normal. And I have no way to judge whether to trust ANOVA for the data that matter. // For my fake shifted-gamma data, `oneway.test` gave about the same P-values as K-W; t.test for Gp2 vs. Gp 3 has larger P-value than Wilcoxon signed rank, but still significant.

Comment: @BruceET Yes. I wonder if there’s any sensitivity analyses of sorts that can help determine if the extent of normality violation warrant the use of nonparametric tests. I roughly remember that normality violation would render inflated type I error for ANOVA. But I thought that nonparametric test can have low power. So I was wondering if there’s some sort of pre-analysis one can do to help decide between the two.

Comment: To OP, what do the data look like per each category? Do they look like they’d share the same distribution?

Comment: @QmmmmLiu. I look for outliers and aggressive skewness, but I know of nothing more systematic or reliable than that--before the fact. If trying ANOVA, I Iook at residuals from ANOVA model, then junk the ANOVA if I don't like what I see. Not sure whether to call this is a recommendation or a confession. // You seem to want to avoid K-W, a phobia I do not share.

Comment: @BruceET thanks. That helps a lot. I also found an article with simulation studies that seems to suggest K-W can be overall advantageous in this situation too. https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/full/10.1111/j.2044-8317.2012.02047.x

Answer (score 4):

You have three levels in the categorical variable about smoking (Current, Never, Former) and obtain (presumably nonnormal) data for $r$ subjects at each level. I'd use a Kruskal-Wallis test to see if the medians differ among levels.

**Fake shifted-gamma data and boxplots:**

```
set.seed(718)
x1 = rgamma(10, 5, 1/5);  x2 = 2+rgamma(10, 5, 1/5);  x3 = 15+rgamma(10, 5, 1/5)
x = c(x1, x2, x3);  g = as.factor(rep(1:3, each=10)) 
median(x1); median(x2); median(x3)
[1] 20.92121
[1] 28.15298
[1] 36.45878

boxplot(x ~ g, col="skyblue2", pch=20)
```

[image]

The 'notches' in the sides of the boxes are approximate nonparametric confidence
intervals for individual group population medians.

**Test of significance:**

A Kruskal-Wallis test finds significant differences among medians at significance
level $\alpha = 0.005.$

```
kruskal.test(x ~ g)

    Kruskal-Wallis rank sum test

data:  x by g
Kruskal-Wallis chi-squared = 11.507, df = 2, p-value = 0.003172
```

*Paired comparisons.* One method to check for differences between pairs of groups (levels) would be to
use the 'notches' in the boxplots, which are calibrated for pairwise comparisons (overlapping notches indicate no significance). A more formal method would be to use two-sample Wilcoxon (rank sum) tests. The difference between Groups 1 and 2 is not
significant an any reasonable level because of the P-value $0.22 > 0.05:$

```
wilcox.test(x1, x2)

    Wilcoxon rank sum test

data:  x1 and x2
W = 33, p-value = 0.2176
alternative hypothesis: true location shift is not equal to 0
```

But the difference between Groups 2 and 3 is highly significant with P-value 0.002 (computation not shown). In this particular instance, paired comparisons
from boxplot notches and from Wilcoxon tests agree.